# Why would you store json as a string inside of json

Tags: javascript, json, youtube, developer-tools

[Screenshot of developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdz18.png)

**When I looked at local storage when visiting youtube, I found some really weird looking json.**

```js
{
    creation: 1638112285935,
    data: "{\"quality\":1080,\"previousQuality\":360}",
    expiration: 1669216285935,
}
```

Why are there json inside of a string inside json? What is the reasoning behind storing it like this? Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's simply used to let the value of data dynamic. when need to use the value, a conversion from string to object is done ( JSON.parse(data) ). Then the object can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure but its possibly beacause this data is stored on mysql.
in mysql you cant store data as type "json".
so to store json in mysql you need to set the datatype "TEXT" and do a JSON.stringify() on the json before storing it in mysql.
I hope my answer is clear I have poor English